# Two languages JS files

Tags: i18n-l10n

In my *default/files/languages* folder I have two JS files:

```
es_BW4ZdvqK9tDPZ0JRAIb4Da2ATqVPvi01H1gYXugKgWo.js
es_iXHy-aczd8O7uaoQze0vEQJL0ROMrskX7l3yWYGxC9r.js
```

They are very similar, but one has some missing translations. The one with missing translations is the one that Drupal uses. Therefore some of my strings are not being translated.

I have tried deleting the unwanted file, but after clearing the cache it is always regenerated.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact issue? or having two files is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that one of the files does not contain all of the translations. It's this file that is used build the `drupalTranslations` object, and therefore some texts are not being translated.

Comment: dbj44, Could you please mention here some text that are not translating?